# How to get value of XAML Control from DataTemplate

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I try to get a value from my TextBox on a button click event which is defined in my XAML data template as the following:

```
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Ausstattung">
                <Grid Height="40" Width="Auto" Background="LightSlateGray" >

                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Foreground="White" FontSize="14" Text="{x:Bind Beschreibung}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Foreground="White" FontSize="14" Text="{x:Bind Ausgabedatum}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Foreground="White" FontSize="14" Text="{x:Bind Rückgabedatum}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Foreground="White" FontSize="14" x:Name="txtAnzahl" PlaceholderText="{x:Bind Anzahl}" TextChanged="TextBox_OnTextChanged" Width="50" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="4" Margin="-25">

                        //here I want to get the value from the TextBox named "txtAnzahl"
                        <Button Height="30" Width="30" Margin="0,10,10,10" Padding="0" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">
                            <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Foreground="LimeGreen" Text="" FontSize="20"/>
                        </Button>
                        <Button Height="30" Width="30" Margin="0,10,10,10" Padding="0">
                            <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Foreground="DarkRed" Text="" FontSize="16"/>
                        </Button>

                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
```

So I try to get the value from the Textbox "txtanzahl" on the Button OnClick event.

Here is what it looks like in the live visual tree:
[image]

I tried to accomplish it with the VisualTreeHelper but I only found examples of GetChild or GetParent but in this case, it is not a child nor a parent.

Also I cannot get the control with the given name "txtAnzahl" like this:

```
var anzahl = txtAnzahl.Text;
```

It says that he didn´t know this element.

Comment: Is this UWP or WPF?

Comment: It is UWP........

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the `Button`'s parent (i.e. `StackPanel`), and then its parent's parent (i.e. `Grid`), and then go down and find the `TextBox`.

But... **Don't do this**. What if you changed the hierarchy, or the type of the `Panel`?

Since you already know the *type* (i.e. `Ausstattung`) of the `DataContext` of your data template, you should create another property say `TextValue` and have it *two-way* bound with the `TextBox`. Then, you can either get its value from a `CommandParameter` if you use `Button`'s `Command`, or in code-behind -

```
private void ButtonBase_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var button = (ButtonBase)sender;
    var dataContext = (Ausstattung)button.DataContext;
    var value = dataContext.TextValue;
}
```

---

Your class needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. After that, create a new property like this -

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using App1.Annotations;

namespace App1
{
    public class Ausstattung : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _textValue;
        public string TextValue
        {
            get => _textValue;
            set
            {
                _textValue = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

In your xaml, do this -

```
<TextBox Text="{x:Bind TextValue, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="3" Foreground="White" FontSize="14" x:Name="txtAnzahl" PlaceholderText="{x:Bind Anzahl}" TextChanged="TextBox_OnTextChanged" Width="50" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by two way bound? I already have the property "Anzahl" which contains the value which is shown in the textbox...

Comment: I tried your solution with datacontext.Anzahl but it only shows the value which is in my class "Ausstattung" but I want to get the value which the user typed in the TextBox and then write it in my class "Ausstattung"

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I cannot add the interface INotifyPropertyChanged. It says it does not implement the member "INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged" and it doesn´t find the method "OnPropertyChanged"

Comment: Maybe it is relevant for you to know, that my class is coming from a wcf webservice

Comment: You just need to implement it. I just updated my answer again with full code. I strongly recommend you to have a read on what `INotifyPropertyChanged` is, and why we need it. Here's a good [start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.inotifypropertychanged). But also keep in mind that if you only ever need data passed from UI to code, not the other way around, you don't need the interface at all.

Comment: thank you very much my friend, it is working now. PS: I also followed you on twitter for your awesome animations <3

Comment: I think you can find visual by name.

Comment: @lindexi, you cannot use `FindName` if the two controls are in different context. Also, like I already explained. Even it's doable, it's not the deal way to solve such problem.

Answer (score 0):

The XAML inside a `DataTemplate` is a bit special; while it's only written once, at runtime it will be copied and used for each item in the list. This makes it hard to reference the correct element inside the data template. If you have 20 items in the list `txtAnzahl` might refer to any of them.

The best solution is to put the content inside the data template in a separate `UserControl`. That way you can reference elements and bind as you normally would.

You can read a bit about `UserControl` in the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.usercontrol#examples).